# i can't write more than 40 columns at a time in excel with openxml

Tags: c#, openxml

I am making a program in c# with openxml that needs to write data to an excel file, cell by cell. Whenever I exceed 40 columns written (regardless of the number of rows), however, the data previously written in the same row is deleted.
so if I have 140 columns in the file and I try to write only the first 40, it does it correctly, if I want it to write them all, I end up with the first 100 columns empty and the last 40 correctly filled.
Can you figure out why it gives this problem? I am attaching the affected portion of the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tempName.Length; i++)
{
    if (columnsExcel[Columnindex].ToLower() == tempName[i].ToLower())
    {
        int index = InsertTextExcel.InsertSharedStringItem(tempValue[i].ToString(), ShareStringPart);

        Cell cell = InsertTextExcel.InsertCellInWorksheet(convertlettertonumber(Columnindex + 2), (uint)rowindex, theWorksheet);

        // Set cell value
        cell.CellValue = new CellValue(index.ToString());
        cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.SharedString);
        theWorksheet.Save();
    }
}
```

tempvalue and tempname are string arrays, sharestringpart is defined as: `SharedStringTablePart shareStringPart = doc.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().First()`

I have already tried writing instead of row by row, column by column, but the result is exactly the same.

Comment: Can you add the InsertTextExcel code?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/E8arHvQ6 here it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not showing all of your code (i.e. where do Columnindex and rowIndex come from?) I can't be entirely sure what the problem is, but I have a hunch that it is this: Rows and cells must be in the correct order in the xml, or else Excel will ignore them. You should even get an error message in Excel saying that the workbook is corrupted and that it can be repaired by removing the offending elements.

Your function InsertCellInWorksheet simply appends rows at the end. This won't work if you call it out of order - in that case the rows have to be inserted at the correct position. Same goes for cells.

The below code inserts cell and rows at the correct position. See if it fixes your problem.

```
private DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell InsertCell(CellAddress address, WorksheetPart OXLWorksheetPart)
{
  DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row row = GetRowByIndex((uint)address.RowIndex, OXLWorksheetPart);

  DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell() { CellReference = address.ToString() };
  // same logic as with rows...find the correct position to insert the cell.
  DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell insertBeforeCell = row.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.CellReference.Value.Length == cell.CellReference.Value.Length && c.CellReference > cell.CellReference);

  if (insertBeforeCell != null)
  {
      row.InsertBefore(cell, insertBeforeCell);
  }
  else
  {
      row.Append(cell);
  }

  return cell;
}


private DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row GetRowByIndex(uint rowIndex, WorksheetPart OXLWorksheetPart)
{
  SheetData sheetData = OXLWorksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

 // Check if the worksheet contains a row with the specified row index.
 DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row row = sheetData.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex);
 if (row == null)
 {
     // the row does not exist yet. Since we have to insert the new row at the correct position, find the first row with the index > the index we want to insert
     // and then insert before that row.
     row = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row() { RowIndex = rowIndex };
     DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row insertBeforeRow = sheetData.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.RowIndex > rowIndex);

     if (insertBeforeRow != null)
     {
         sheetData.InsertBefore(row, insertBeforeRow);
     }
     else
     {
         sheetData.Append(row);
     }
 }

  return row;
}




public class CellAddress
{
 public int ColumnIndex { get; set; }
 public string ColumnName { get; set;}
 public int RowIndex { get; set;}

 public override string ToString() => $"{ColumnName}{RowIndex}";
}
```

BTW if you don't have specific reasons to use OpenXML, I would recommend something like [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) since it is way easier to use and makes sure the created XML conforms to all the rules.